# Showing that the balls respect to Wasserstein metric with equal radius in $\mathcal{P}_{p}(\Xi)$ and $\mathcal{P}(\Xi)$ respectively are equal.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification, coupling

Before presenting my question (which I already formulate in the title of this post)  is important to establish the context of my problem:

> **Definition:**
>   The $p$-Wasserstein metric $W_{p}(\mu,\nu)$ between $\mu,\nu\in\mathcal{P}_{p}(\Xi)$ is defined by
>   $$W_{p}^{p}(\mu,\nu):=\min_{\Pi\in\mathcal{P}(\Xi\times\Xi)}\left\{\int_{\Xi\times\Xi}d^{p}(\xi,\zeta)\Pi(d\xi,d\zeta)\: :\: \Pi(\cdot \times\Xi)=\mu(\cdot),\: \Pi(\Xi\times\cdot)=\nu(\cdot)\right\}$$
>   where 
>   $$\mathcal{P}_{p}(\Xi):=\left\{\mu\in\mathcal{P}(\Xi)\: :\: \int_{\Xi}d^{p}(\xi,\zeta_{0})\mu(d\xi) < \infty\ \mbox{for some }\zeta_{0}\in\Xi\right\}$$
>   where $d$ is a metric on  $\Xi$.

The $p$-Wasserstein metric (with $p\geq 1$) is also defined for any measure in $\mathcal{P}(\Xi)$ the space of all the measures of probability, the only difference is that in that set it can take values as infinite.

Given $\varepsilon>0$ and $\mu\in\mathcal{P}_{p}(\Xi)$ we define 
$$\mathcal{B}_{\varepsilon}^{p}(\mu):=\left\{\nu\in\mathcal{P}_{p}(\Xi)\:|\: W_{p}(\mu,\nu)\leq \varepsilon \right\}$$
and
$$\mathcal{B}_{\varepsilon}(\mu):=\left\{\nu\in\mathcal{P}(\Xi)\:|\: W_{p}(\mu,\nu)\leq \varepsilon \right\}.$$

**The question:** I want to know if the following is correct:
$$\mathcal{B}_{\varepsilon}(\mu)=\mathcal{B}_{\varepsilon}^{p}(\mu).$$

**My attempt:** We know that  $\mathcal{P}_{p}(\Xi)\subset \mathcal{P}(\Xi)$, then 
$$\mathcal{B}_{\varepsilon}^{p}(\mu)\subseteq\mathcal{B}_{\varepsilon}(\mu).$$
For other hand,  if $\nu\in \mathcal{B}_{\varepsilon}(\mu)$ then $W_{p}(\nu,\mu)\leq \varepsilon$ then by infimum definition there exists $\Pi\in\mathcal{P}(\Xi\times\Xi)$ such that $\Pi(\cdot\times \Xi)=\nu$,  $\Pi(\Xi\times \cdot)=\mu$ and 
$$\int_{\Xi\times\Xi}d^{p}(\xi,\zeta)\Pi(d\xi,d\zeta)\leq \varepsilon.\tag{*} $$
Therefore, due to the convexity of $x^{p}$, $p$ is positive integer with $p\geq 1$, $\mu\in\mathcal{P}_{p}(\Xi)$ and the triangle inequality we have
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\int_{\Xi}d^p(\xi_{0},\xi)\nu(d\xi) &=& \int_{\Xi\times\Xi} d^p(\xi,\xi_{0})\Pi(d\xi,d\zeta) \\
&=& 2^{p} \int_{\Xi\times\Xi} \left(\frac{d(\xi,\xi_{0})}{2}\right)^{p}\Pi(d\xi,d\zeta) \\
&\leq & 2^{p-1}\int_{\Xi\times\Xi} d^p(\xi_{0},\zeta)\Pi(d\xi,d\zeta)+ 2^{p-1}\int_{\Xi\times\Xi} d^p(\xi,\zeta)\Pi(d\xi,d\zeta) \\
&\leq& 2^{p-1}\int_{\Xi\times\Xi} d^p(\xi_{0},\zeta)\Pi(d\xi,d\zeta)+ 2^{p-1}\varepsilon \\
&=& 2^{p-1}\int_{\Xi} d^p(\xi_{0},\zeta)\mu(d\zeta)+ 2^{p-1}\varepsilon \\ &<&\infty.
\end{array}
$$
Therefore, $\nu\in\mathcal{P}_{p}(\Xi)$, so $\nu\in\mathcal{B}_{\varepsilon}^{p}(\mu)$.

**Remark:** The previous attempt was made after several attempts, when I was very tired, so it is highly likely that I can go wrong. **Is my attempt correct? Do I have an error in my attempt?**  If my attempt is incorrect, I would appreciate it if you would give me an answer to my question.

---

**Addemdum:**

I calmly set myself the task of analyzing my proof, I realized that it has an error, although the fact that I try to show is true. Questions like the one I proposed are very common in the knowledge exams of Masters or Phd's, if you want the correct demonstration of the fact that I propose let me know, but ideally you should identify the error of my attempt, it is a good exercise.